# Crystal Report - Failed to open report with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, rpt, reportdocument

I am getting below error when reportDocument.SetDataSource(dt) called.

```
System.Exception: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800003E5): Failed to open report.
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
```

Workflow:

I am using ReportDocument object to export the excel through RPT file. Recently, I have upgraded crystal report made in VS2008 into VS2017. All other rpt reports are working fine except one. When I run using VS 2008 code, it is working fine but in VS 2017 it is giving error.

Please anybody help on this?

Comment: 1) What is your Database ? 2) Would you please show us the code you use with a clarification of the line which generates this Error?

Comment: Database is oracle. Code which throws error reportdocument.Refresh() line. Even though, if I set static values datatable, then also it didn't work.

Comment: Please add those Info to your question. Now, have you tried connecting your CR manually without using the code, there is  a good example here [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28330/Using-Crystal-Report-with-Oracle-and-parametrized)